# Mustache TypeError: Invalid template! Template should be a "string" but "undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, mustache

I am learning mustache.js client side template but it doesn't work very well. 
In the following codes example, I tried to display a list of students in table based on the year option selected.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/mustache.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" style="margin-top:3%">
    <label>Year</label>
    <select id="year" onchange="refreshList(this)">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="2019">2019</option>
        <option value="2018">2018</option>
    </select>
    <br /><br />
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Registered Date</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="studentsList">
            <script type="text/template" id="studentsTemplate">
            {{#students}}
                <tr class='row_{{id}}'>
                <td>{{registered}}</td>
                <td>{{name}}</td>
                <td>{{age}}</td>
                </tr>
            {{/students}}
           </script>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<script>

var testing = {
        "name" : "student-collection",
        "students" : [
            {
                "id" : 97,
                "registered" : "2018-03-01",
                "name" : "John",
                "age" : 20
            },
            {
                "id" : 118,
                "registered" : "2019-04-01",
                "name" : "Mary",
                "age" : 21
            },
            {
                "id" : 509,
                "registered" : "2018-08-01",
                "name" : "Dave",
                "age" : 19
            }
        ]
    };

    function inYear(registerYear){
        return function(student){
            var date = new Date(student.registered);
            return date.getFullYear() == Number(registerYear);
        }
    }


    function refreshList(selected){
        var filters = testing.students.filter(inYear(selected.value));

        var html = Mustache.render($('#studentsTemplate').html(), {students : filters});
        var list = $("#studentsList");
        list.empty();
        list.append(html);
    }

    function refreshList2(selected){
        var filters = testing.students.filter(inYear(selected.value));

        var html = Mustache.render($('#studentsTemplate').html(), {students : filters});
        document.getElementById("studentsList").innerHTML = html;
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I selected the 'year' drop down for first time, the table did display correctly. 
However, there was "TypeError: Invalid template! Template should be a "string" but "undefined" was given as the first argument..." error occurred if different year in drop down list was selected afterwards.

I think this is because the 'studentsTemplate' had been removed when I empty the 'studentsList' in `refreshList()` function. 
It doesn't help too if I set the innerHTML directly as in the refreshList2().

How to clear the student rows in table without affecting the 'studentsTemplate' template?

Comment: Move the template out of the element you're trying to put stuff in.

Comment: @Henrik Andersson   
My intention is to make the view more readable, by putting template there so that all htmls are in one place. it is a common practice when using the server-side mustache or thymeleaf, to have the template at the exact same place where the html will be rendered (like in my codes above). Moving the template out of that place will defeat the purpose of using the template system, right?

Comment: So insteady of `list.empty()` just remove the rendered `tr`s. That way you'll keep the template there and just append the new instead of replacing. The benefit of not doing what you're doing is that you get a nice separation of concerns plus that you can load the templates separately.